# Permission denied while querying Win32_Printer in ASP.NET on IIS using Application Pool Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, printing

I am querying Win32_Printer in ASP.net code on IIS using Application Pool Identity (Windows 2016 Server machine). On one of the server I am getting Access denied error. The code work fine on other servers. I compared the two servers but unable to find difference in permissions. What permissions do I need to give to IIS App Pool Identity user to make this call? Here is the code snippet.

---

```
        public static List<string> GetPrinterNames()
    {
        var query = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
        var searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        var printerList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var dummyPrinterObject in searcher.Get())
        {
            printerList.Add(dummyPrinterObject["DeviceID"] as string);
        }

        return printerList;
    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that on other servers app pool identity is set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity` and not other custom or predefined identity e.g. `LocalService`

Comment: this will return the printer list of web server to the clients.  are you sure you want it this way ?

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood, yes. the identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity. As a side note, setting it to LocalService actually displays printer. but I don't want to use LocaService. Instead, I want to give ApplicationPoolIdentity or IIS_USR permission to query the printer list.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari, yes Manoj. We want user to select a printer from list and print document from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
public static System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.StringCollection InstalledPrinters { get; }
```

The example is shown at [this documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
private void PopulateInstalledPrintersCombo()
{
    // Add list of installed printers found to the combo box.
    // The pkInstalledPrinters string will be used to provide the display string.
    String pkInstalledPrinters;
    for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++){
        pkInstalledPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i];
        comboInstalledPrinters.Items.Add(pkInstalledPrinters);
    }
}
```